# MSYS2 path to Windows clipboard

Tags: msys2

Is there a way to copy a Unix path from the MSYS2 bash shell to the Windows clipboard?

A work-around is to start a Windows explorer with the current directory: `/c/windows/explorer .`

Answer (score 0):

The MSYS2 `pwd` command has a `-W` switch to output the current path as Windows path (with forward slashes).

The Windows clipboard can be accessed [as a Unix device](https://github.com/Alexpux/MSYS2-packages/issues/581): `/dev/clipboard`

So this makes a shell function like this:

```
# pathw [-c] [dir]

pathw () {
    local p=''
    local clip=false

    if [ "$1x" = "-cx" ]; then
        clip=true
        shift
    fi

    if [ "$1x" = "x" ]; then
        p=$(pwd -W)
    else
        p=$(cd $1 && pwd -W)
    fi

    p=$(echo $p | sed 's|/|\\|g')

    echo $p

    if [ "$clip" = true ]; then
        echo $p > /dev/clipboard
    fi
}

pathw ~

C:\msys64\home\weberjn
```